# Тюнинг Oracle

Tags: oracle, книги

Вдогонку к предыдущему вопросу про JasperReports... Посоветуйте книжку по тюнингу оракла, есть варианты, надо бы выбрать, что купить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что вас интересует. Книг много:

- Oracle9i XML. Разработка приложений электронной коммерции с использованием технологии XML
- Секреты Oracle SQL
- Oracle PL/SQL для администраторов баз данных
- Oracle 10g. Настольная книга администратора баз данных
- Oracle9i Certified Associate. Подготовка администраторов баз данных
- 101 Oracle. Как написать мощные и гибкие программы на Pl, SQL
- Oracle 9iR2. Разработка и эксплуатация хранилищ баз данных
- ...

Можно сделать выбор исходя из описания.

Comment: интересует по вот этой теме:

Кэрри Миллсап, Д. Хольт 
Oracle. Оптимизация производительности 

это вроде бы все, что сейчас есть в продаже. Может еще что-то есть подобное? Сравнить бы

Comment: Если вас интересуют вопросы оптимизации, то есть ещё такая книга: "101 Oracle. Настройка производительности".